# Resize events in jQuery FullCalendar

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fullcalendar

How to change the event size in the cell of a FullCalendar.

Every event in my calendar is an image, so currently if more than one image shows, they display vertically. But I want to show all the events horizontally.

I tried to modify its css, used `float: left, display: inline`, but no luck. Also changed the size of each image to `11px`, but no luck

Please see my live site: http://oryxtesting.com/learning-events/

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the images are being absolutely positioned and forced to look like they are positioned nicely in the calendar. The elements are not even within the table cells, they are just overlayed above the table.

Also, the images are not inheriting the width of 11px, as they are given an inline width of 54px.

The fix isn't easy. You need to either correct the script to insert the images inside the calendar table cells. Or, you need to absolutely position them so that they appear to be on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

I added an eventRender to the calendar in month view.... here's my code:

```
eventRender: function(event, element, view) { 
    var diff=datediff(view.visStart,event.start);   //note datediff if a self-made function which returns the number of days between calendar start view and current day
    var rows=parseInt(diff/7); 
    var cols=diff;
    element.css('position','static'); 
    $('tr.fc-week'+rows+' td.fc-day'+cols+' div.fc-day-content div:first').append($(element));
}
```